# Importing CSV files using VBA query table, does delete upper data rows

Tags: excel, vba, csv

This is my code

```
Sub ImportCSVFile(xFileName As String, ByRef xTargetRange As Range)

    With xTargetRange.Parent.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & xFileName, xTargetRange)
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 936
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

This block of code works fine, but the problem is when want to import data to for example to Range(A4), the data (upper rows) will be deleted (contents and formats). The question is, Is it a way to preserve this data?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim s As String
    
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("ExcelFile *.txt,*.txt;*.csv", _
       Title:="Select CSV file", MultiSelect:=False)

    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    
    s = vFile
    
    ImportCSVFile s, Range("a4")

End Sub


Sub ImportCSVFile(xFileName As String, ByRef xTargetRange As Range)
    Dim WbCSV As Workbook
    Dim vDB As Variant
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set WbCSV = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xFileName, Format:=2)
    
    With WbCSV.Sheets(1)
        vDB = .UsedRange
    End With

    WbCSV.Close (0)

    xTargetRange.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

    enter code here
```